# Function returning a class implementing an interface: missing properties

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Typescript 3.9
I want to create a factory function which returns a class implementing a specific interface:

```
export interface A<T>{
  list(): Promise<T>
}

export function Factory<T>(): A<T> {
  class AHost implements A<T>{
    async list() {
      return {} as any
    }
  }
  return AHost
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
Property 'list' is missing in type 'typeof AHost' but required in type 'A<T>'.
```

despite the fact that `list` is defined on `AHost`. This is heavily inspired on [NestJS author's talk](https://youtu.be/jo-1EUxMmxc?t=3235). I'm unable to use it 1-to-1 because when I use `Type` I get `TS2315: Type 'Type' is not generic.` error.

A bigger picture is: I want to create an abstract service with EntityClassOrSchema (Typeorm) as an input argument for the factory function so that I can easily generate services for various entities.

Comment: You're returning a *class*, not an *instance*. `return new AHost()` would work fine, because that is an instance implementing `A<T>`. Alternatively, as you want to return the class, having the return type be e.g. `{ new(): A<T> }` would work.

Comment: That was quick. Thank you.

Comment: Having return type ClassType<A<T>>  works for me.

Comment: I don't know what ClassType is, but you can see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#constructor-functions for information about the *static side* vs. *instance side* of classes.

Comment: It's a `export declare type ClassType<T> = {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
};` from class-transformer package. Sorry I didn't notice where was it coming from. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your factory interface expects the A instance but not the A class

You should change your factory type to something like this

```
export interface A<T>{
  list(): Promise<T>
}
// add type of class there
export type B<T> = new () => A<T>

export function Factory<T>(): B<T> {
  class AHost implements A<T>{
    async list() {
      return {} as any
    }
  }
  return AHost
}
```